# How to init multiprocessing class in a flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I've been following [Miguel Grinberg's Flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure), my application has the same structure (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.22).

I now want to add a multiprocessing function inside a class that is listening on a queue, but I'm not sure how to initialize it the right way.

As suggested [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure) in the tutorial, my init looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
# and so on

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
# and so on

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    # and so on 

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    # and so on

    from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)
    # and so on

    return app

from app import models
```

The multiprocessing class is in a file called worker.py:

```
class Worker(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._pool = None
        self._in_q = Queue()

    def start(self):
        self._pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
        self._thread = Thread(target=self._process, args=(), daemon=True)
        self._thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._pool.close()
        self._pool.join()
        self._pool = None
        self.result_q.put(None)

    def _process(self):
        while True:
            task = self._in_q.get()
            if task is None:
                print("shutdown")
                return
            self._pool.apply_async(_work, (w,), callback=finished)

    def do_work(self):
        # Work on something here
        return self

def _work(value):
    value = Worker.do_work(value)
    return value

def finished(self):
    print("I am done.")
```

I guess I now need to initialise the worker somewhere in my init once in order to be able to put things in the queue from various other places in my app then, but I neither understand how to initialise it, nor how to call it from other parts.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to put it outside the flask app and keep it running there. There is no need to do this inside the flask app.